# Question about linear operator and Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Define the Fourier transform on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ in the usual way by a limiting process from
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{f}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2\pi i xy}f(x)dy.
\end{eqnarray*}
Fix $m\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Show that the equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
\widehat{(Tf)}(y)=m(y)\hat{f}(y)
\end{eqnarray*}
defines a boudend linear operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

How to show that $T$ is bounded?

Comment: Compositions of bounded linear operators are bounded...$f \mapsto \hat{f}$ is a unitary on $L^2$ and multiplication by $m$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** use Plancherel's formula $\lVert \widehat f\rVert_2=\lVert f\rVert_2$ in order to get 
$$\lVert T(f)\rVert_2=\lVert m\cdot \widehat f\rVert_2\leqslant \lVert m\rVert_\infty\lVert \widehat f\rVert_2.$$